# Bitmap rotation in circular path CreateJS Tweenjs

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, createjs

I'm trying to rotate a bird in circular path but the problem is the **to** method doesn't give much control to do the exact thing, I 'm trying to move the bird head up or down with the rotation.

Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/HF765/142/

```
 var tween = createjs.Tween.get(shape, {loop: true})
    .to({x: 100 , y: 100, rotation: 0}, 0)
    .to({x: 200 , y: 200, rotation: 90}, 2000)
    .to({x: 100 , y: 300, rotation: 180}, 2000)
    .to({x: 0 , y: 200, rotation: 270}, 2000)
    .to({x: 100 , y: 100, rotation: 360}, 2000)
```

I want to rotate it in a circle, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rotation seems to be working correctly in your example, but you are tweening the bird around a diamond shape (with straight paths), so it looks weird.

One easy way to get the effect you're looking for is to offset the bird's center point using `regX` and `regY`, and then rotate it. If you imagine the bird was cut out of a piece of paper, this is like attaching a stick pointing down from the center of it and rotating it using the stick. See an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/HF765/143/

Another option is to look at the `MotionGuidePlugin` for TweenJS. It's more complicated to work with, but offers a lot of control, including the ability to have the target rotate along the path.

http://www.createjs.com/Docs/TweenJS/classes/MotionGuidePlugin.html